# Is secure to push sensitive data to Amazon SQS?

Tags: amazon-sqs

As per the object, is secure to push sensitive data to Amazon SQS?

For example, I want a user sets its credentials in a form on website A, so website will push a message that is then pulled by Website B, so website B can create an account.

So, is this flow secure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are worried about security, then you should be worried about putting sensitive data in an SQS queue. Anyone that has/obtains sufficient privileges or access within the AWS infrastructure could read you messages.

One option is for message producer to encrypt the message before sending and the message consumer to decrypt the message upon receipt. The SQS message is a string, so you will have to encode (e.g., base64) your encrypted bytes as a string.

By encrypting before sending and decrypting after receiving, your message is secure.